# Segmentation fault при dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется freebsd 12, собранный из портов Qt5 и GCC7. Любое написанное приложение падает при dynamic_cast. Например:

```
struct base
{
   virtual void test() = 0;
};

struct derived : base
{
   virtual void test() override final {}
};

int main()
{
   base* some_base = new derived();
   derived* seg_fault_now = dynamic_cast<derived*>(some_base);
   return 0;
}
```

Падение происходит в недрах libcxxrt.so.1. Насколько я понял, это библиотека cpp runtime, и она собрана с помощью clang, который является стандартным для freebsd. На лицо несовместимость ПО собранного с помощью gcc и libcxxrt.so.1. Тем более, что если собрать приложение с помощью clang все работает замечательно.

Не совсем понимаю какие у меня есть выходы из данной ситуации. Первое что приходит в голову - возможно есть способ статически линковать рантайм

Comment: Этот код не собирается из-за множества ошибок синтаксиса. А то, что бинарики, собранное разными компиляторами, или даже разными вариантами одного компилятора, или даже одним и тем же, но с разными настройками, в общем случае не являются совместимыми - это не новость. Выхода два - собрать все строго одинаково или использовать С (С89) интерфейс между библиотеками.

Comment: @VTT Опечатку в коде исправил. Проблема в том, что libcxxrt.so.1 - это системная библиотека. Мне бы очень не хотелось использовать clang для сборки своих приложений. Неужели нет нормального способа собирать на gcc под freebsd ?

Comment: Нормального? Нет... Проще воспользоваться виртуализацией / контейнеризацией.

Comment: А если попробывать вместо `dynamic_cast<derived*>` привести в стиле С `(derived*)` ? тоже упадет?

Comment: @NewView упасть то может и не упадет, но проблему это не решает. Здесь вопрос о несовместимости с райнтаймом freebsd, уверен что проблемы с dynamic_cast это лишь верхушка айсберга

Comment: Совместимости нет не в чем, это точно :) можно её не искать, тогда в вашем случае скорей всего придется выбрать цланг или внимательно изучить различия в бинарниках стандартных библиотек с помощью `nm` например.. но думаю это не даст конечного результата. Мне кажется что вероятно есть разница на флагах линкера.